# Can I run Windows Workflow Foundation inside a docker containter

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017, docker-compose, containers, workflow-foundation

I could not find any option to add docker or container support for my Windows Workflow Foundation project. I manage to add for WCF *.csproject in the same solution but cannot see any option for WF *.vbproj.

I could not find anything related to Workflow Foundation and docker while searching in the net. So, is this not supported yet? Can I say that the workflow foundation cannot be run in a container?

I am trying to build a Docker container that basically runs a windows workflow foundation project to run locally. I am not worried about the size. Is it doable?

Comment: I'm researching this currently. As far as I can tell, it is possible, though you will need a console application host which can run the WWF workflow. This will need to intercept log requests and inject input variables, but it should be doable. I'll be open sourcing this activity runner when I finish and I'll respond with an answer should I finish it or find a different/better way of doing this.